# ASP - how to set a combobox text from another control on pageload

Tags: asp.net, binding, datasource

I'm basically creating an edit form page.  And what I have is a few comboboxes that are being populated with possible selected value.  What I want to do is set the text to the current value.  My curve ball is this.  The edit form datasource is coming from `DataSourceA` the combobox is coming from `DataSourceB`.  How do I get the combobox text to be the value of `DataSourceA` on binding?

Comment: Do the combo boxes have the same values in them ?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you good combo box a has the same value as combo box b.

Then you could use the find by text function.

```
Discount3.SelectedValue = Discount3.Items.FindByText(Discount2.SelectedValue).Value;
```